# Cannot equip silencer on self-bought M4A4

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

There are multiple weapons where silencers can be equipped, most importantly the $3100 M4A4. I should be able to equip/remove a silencer with secondary fire which is configured to the default right-mouse button.

Once I pickup someone else's M4A4 with the silencer equipped I can add/remove it as expected.

Before Global Offensive, the silencer had to be bought separately. Now you get the silencer with the gun and it cannot be bought. Maybe I'm not getting the silencer in the package?

Comment: M4A4 is not compatible with silencer. Silencer only comes with M4A1-S.

Comment: How do I get that one? M4A4 can be bought with B 4 2. I cannot find M4A1-S in the buy menu.

Comment: OK, I'll make answer, just wait for me so I can take some screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The silencer is not compatible M4A4, you'd need to change your CT's rifle with M4A1-S.

To do this, first [open your Inventory located in the left menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nouh.png). Afterwards, you'll see your inventory, and if you got skins, boxes, stickers and spray, it'll also show up on this place.

[There's some tabs located in your inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HEU8.png). Click the Rifle tab and you should see your rifles. In this list, you should see your M4A1-S. Click it, and [hit Replace for CT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drmdm.png), and you'll see it in the buy menu when playing.

Keep in mind that M4A4 will be replaced with M4A1-S meaning that you cannot use it during match.